# Race between socket accept and receive

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I am using nodemcu with an esp-32 and recently came across an annoying problem. I refer to this sample from the [NodeMCU Github page](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware):

```
-- a simple HTTP server
srv = net.createServer(net.TCP)
srv:listen(80, function(conn)
    conn:on("receive", function(sck, payload)
        print(payload)
        sck:send("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<h1> Hello, NodeMCU.</h1>")
    end)
    conn:on("sent", function(sck) sck:close() end)
end)
```

This doesn't seem to work in every case.
If I try it with **telnet**, there is no issue:

```
$ telnet 172.17.10.59 80
Trying 172.17.10.59...
Connected to 172.17.10.59.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html

<h1> Hello, NodeMCU.</h1>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

But when using **wget**, it hangs most of the time:

```
$ wget http://172.17.10.59/
--2017-05-12 15:00:09--  http://172.17.10.59/
Connecting to 172.17.10.59:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

After some research, the root cause seems to be, that the *receive callback* is registered *after* the first data was received from the client. This doesn't happen when testing manually with telnet, but with a client like wget or a browser, the delay between connecting and receiving the first data seems to be too small to register the receive handler first.

I have looked into the nodemcu code and there doesn't seem to be an easy way to work around this problem. Or do I miss something here?

Comment: Does the problem persist when using the [`httpserver`](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/lua-modules/httpserver/#httpservercreateserver) Lua module?

Answer (score 0):

In HTTP/1.0, you need the "Content-Length" in the HTTP header when there is a message-body.

For example:

```
"HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nContent-Length: 25 \r\n\r\n<h1> Hello, NodeMCU.</h1>"
```

ref: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html#Content-Length